# Best practices for running and updating multiple separate stores

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, best-practice

3 years ago I was a part of a company that ran magento webshops for many independent customers. What we experienced at the end was that if we wanted to do a change that affects all the shops (bug fix) or an upgrade of magento, we had to do it on a case by case basis.

I would like to get your input on if there is a way to set up a structure that will allow for upgrade all the shops at once and fix common issues for all in a simple way.

Every shop will have the same core, but modules etc might vary. As they each are individual stores.

Comment: You have many different installs or one install and multiple stores?

Comment: Many different installs

Comment: This is assuming that every shop will be identical and will not have any variations on code correct?

Comment: Every shop will have the same core, but modules etc might vary. As they each are individual stores.

Comment: You can symlink the core files but you will still have to deal with each individual store. Not sure how much ahead that will get you

Comment: I'm with brent - symlink is probably the simplest option that is at least discussed online, though not really "documented" - the challenge you face is that as soon as you update one, you've updated all, which means if there are any side effects to custom extensions in each store or to the template themes used on each store those would have to be deployed simultaneously with the core updates.  May not be a big issue but all of sudden that "simple" update may not be as simple as you wanted...

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to set up your Magento projects with [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/). Then you can include the Magento core as a dependency and manage it in a single separate repository with all official updates and patches. You could include custom patches there as well but I would rather keep them in another repository.

This only works if you separate core and customization. If you are already using modman, I have good news for you: the transition is easy.

But coming from several monolithic project repositories it will take some initial effort to separate your customizations from the core.

### How it works

(Instructions for new project setup)

1. Create a repository that includes the Magento core and create a `composer.json` file in it with this content:

   ```
   {
       "name": "magento/ce",
       "type": "magento-source",
       "require": {}
   }
   ```

   You can clone one of the existing mirrors like https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror or https://github.com/firegento/magento which contain all recent community versions including security patches, but you will have to add the `composer.json` (the important bit is `"type": "magento-source"`, which tells the composer installer that this contains the Magento core).
2. Create a `composer.json` file in your projects with this content (replace `url_to_your_magento_repo.git` with the URL of the repository that we created before (for example `git@bitbucket.org:your-company/magento-ce.git`)

   ```
   {
       "require": {
           "aoepeople/composer-installers": "dev-master",
           "magento/ce": "dev-master"
       }
       "minimum-stability": "dev",
       "repositories": [
           {
               "type": "vcs",
               "url": "url_to_your_magento_repo.git"
           },
           {
               "type": "composer",
               "url": "http://packages.firegento.com"
           }
       ],
       "extra":{
           "installer-paths": {
               "www/" : [ "type:magento-source" ],
               ".modman/{$vendor}_{$name}/" : [ "type:magento-module" ]
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This tells composer to install the Magento source to `www` and Magento modules that you might install with composer to `.modman`. You can replace `"magento/ce": "dev-master"` with a specific version or branch. Branches must be prefixed with "dev-".
3. Run `composer install` to install the dependencies (i.e. Magento core)
4. Get [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/) and run `modman init www`. Modman is a tool that creates symlinks to keep your modules seperate from the core.
5. Write all customizations as modules inside of `.modman` with a `modman` file that defines the symlinks, and run `modman deploy MODULE_NAME` to create the symlinks. See modman documentation for details.
6. Custom modules that you use across several sites can be created as separate repositories similar to the Magento core repository, but with `"type": "magento-module"`. Also they must contain a `modman` file. After defining such a repository as a dependency and running `composer update` you will find the module in `.modman` and can use `modman deploy` to create the symlinks.

#### This presentation explains the setup in detail:

[Magento with Composer - Marcel Hauri - Meet Magento CH 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_bOgh-W8WU) (Video, 21 min)

Comment: Very good answer!